# Am I allowed to declare wildcards for LIKE operators prior to their use in the clause?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Just for tidyness purposes, I would like to declare the scalar values of search parameters in a stored procedure of mine (for SQL Server 2012), prior to actually using them in the WHERE clause of my search. So basically I would like to do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [test_select]
      @firstName   VARCHAR(50)
    , @lastName    VARCHAR(50)
AS 

IF @firstName != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @firstName = '%' + @firstName + '%'
    END

IF @lastName != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @lastName = '%' + @lastName + '%'
    END

SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[Member] AS Member

WHERE 
(    @firstName != '' AND @firstName LIKE [Member].[FirstName] )
OR ( @lastName  != '' AND @lastName  LIKE [Member].[LastName]  )
```

I'm still somewhat new to SQL, so my question is simple, is what I'm trying to do here going to insert the wildcards like I expect for use in the LIKE operator?

Comment: You've got the syntax backwards. It should be `[Member].[FirstName] like @firstName`

Comment: Heh, that was actually the other question I was going to ask. Thanks for pointing out that I can not do that (still writing the query in question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Like takes a string.

```
Declare @LikeString nvarchar(max) = '%Name%'

Select *
From  table
Where Column Like @LikeString
```